# Error:error: only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type View?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to code some code from Java to kotlin but i keep gettin the foll error

Error:error: only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type View?

Java Code

```
  View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        // Get the {@link Word} object located at this position in the list
        Word currentWord = getItem(position);

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID miwok_text_view.
        TextView miwokTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.miwok_text_view);
```

After converting to kotlin

```
  var listView:View? =convertView
        if(listView==null){
            listView=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false)
        }

        var currentWord:Word=getItem(position)

        val miwokTextView= listView.findViewById(R.id.miwok_text_view) as TextView
```

I am getting error at listView.findViewById, even after including ? or !!,the error won't disappear.I even tried the online converter from JetBrains and when i paste the converted code to android studio,i still keep getting the error.Please help

I tried with `val miwokTextView= listView?.findViewById(R.id.miwok_text_view) as TextView` and `val miwokTextView= listView!!.findViewById(R.id.miwok_text_view) as TextView` but i am still getting error at findViewById

Comment: "even after including ? or !!" 
Post the code *with* included ? or !!

Comment: @Ascorbin I tried with val miwokTextView= listView?.findViewById(R.id.miwok_text_view) as TextView and val miwokTextView= listView!!.findViewById(R.id.miwok_text_view) as TextView
        but i am still getting error at findViewById

Comment: If you remove the `as TextView` cast following the use of either of those does it have an impact? You may not be able to cast to a non-nullable type when using `?` because it allows for null to propagate.

Comment: @dillius even after removing as TextView cast,i am getting the error

Comment: I'm not sure why the error is occurring, but maybe this can work around it:

Wrap that bit of code in another if statement:

    `if(listView != null)`

Kotlin will smart cast listView to a non-nullable type and it should then be impossible for you to get that error.

Answer (score 1):

Got it
 val miwokTextView = listView?.findViewById`<`View`>`(R.id.miwok_text_view) as TextView

Comment: This is exactly the same thing you said you tried in the question, but with an extra space.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type `val` into `var` like this format.Because val cant be reassigned.

```
var miwokTextView= listView?.findViewById<View>(R.id.miwok_text_view) as TextView
```

Comment: Even if i write val it is not a problem.I forgot to add `<View>` after findViewById

Comment: ok . when you going to use  miwokTextView as global use as var instead of val .. now its solved?